# CSS Sibling Elements Increased Spacing

Tags: html, css, position

I have an unordered list and I am trying to add more space between them as I add items.  So, the first item has a 5px right-hand margin, the second has a 10px right-hand margin, etc.  I'm able to achieve this by using the :nth-child(n) pseudo-class.  But that means that I have to create a rule for every item (i.e. if I have 6 items in my list, I have to have 6 :nth-child(n)).

Is there a way to code this that doesn't require me to provide a rule for each li?

- The HTML cannot change
- Only use JavaScript for CSS selector/property fallback (i.e. Dean Edwards IE7), HTML5 support (i.e. shim/v), etc.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S2ySk/6/)

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <nav class="nav1">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://example.com/1">Hello World 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://example.com/2">Hello World 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://example.com/3">Hello World 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://example.com/4">Hello</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <img src="http://markschamel.com/upload/blue.square.png" />
    <nav class="nav2">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://example.com/1">Hello World</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://example.com/2">Hello</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #c87137;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
nav {
    min-width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
}
nav.nav1 {
    text-align: right;
}
nav.nav2 {
    text-align: left;
}
nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
nav li {
    background-color: #008000;
    border: 1px solid black;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
nav.nav1 li {
    float: right;
}
nav.nav2 li {
    float: left;
}
nav.nav1 li:nth-child(1) { margin-right: 0px; }
nav.nav1 li:nth-child(2) { margin-right: 5px; }
nav.nav1 li:nth-child(3) { margin-right: 10px; }
nav.nav1 li:nth-child(4) { margin-right: 15px; }

nav.nav2 li:nth-child(1) { margin-left: 0px; }
nav.nav2 li:nth-child(2) { margin-left: 5px; }
nav.nav2 li:nth-child(3) { margin-left: 10px; }
nav.nav2 li:nth-child(4) { margin-left: 15px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do calculations in CSS so you either have to calculate the increasing margins in JS or define the margins for a set number of children in CSS. A CSS preprocessor like SAS or LESS  could make this process less painfull but other than that there aren't any options, its a CSS limitations all of us have to live with :).

Comment: Since I got an upvote on this - you CAN do calculations in CSS these days, but the options with psuedo selectors are still quite limited and the original question still can't be solved with just CSS. Having said that, if you use a modern js framework such as React, Vue this would be peanuts.